# Split up 32 bit value in C++ and concatenate the chunks in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm working on a project where I have to send values of 32 bits over UART to MATLAB where I need to print them in the MATLAB terminal. I do this by splitting up the 32 bit value into 8 bit values like so (:

```
void Configurator::send(void) {

    /**
     * Split the 32 bits in chunks of 4 bytes of 8 bits
     */
    union {
        uint32_t data;
        uint8_t bytes[4];
    } splitData;

    splitData.data = 1234587;

    for (int n : splitData.bytes) {
        XUartPs_SendByte(STDOUT_BASEADDRESS, splitData.bytes[n]);
    }

}
```

In MATLAB I receive the following 4 bytes:

```
   252
   230
    25
   155
```

Now the question is, how do I restore the `1234587`?

Am I correct in creating an array of size 4 as `uint8_t`? I would also like to note that I'm using union for readability. If I'm doing it wrong, I'd be happy to hear why!

Answer (score 0):

You could use left shift to restore the value

```
uint32_t value = (byte[3]<<24) + (byte[2]<<16) + (byte[1]<<8) + (byte[0]<<0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using unions for this sort of thing.  It is not (in principle) portable, and can cause undefined behaviour.  Instead write it like this:

```
void Configurator::send(void) {

    /**
     * Split the 32 bits in chunks of 4 bytes of 8 bits
     */
    uint32_t data = 1234587;

    for (int n = 0; n<4; n++) {
        unsigned char octet = (data >> (n*8)) & 0xFF;
        XUartPs_SendByte(STDOUT_BASEADDRESS, octet);
    }
}

uint32_t recieveBytes(
{
    uint32_t result = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n<4; n++)
    {
        unsigned char octet = getOctet();
        uint32_t octet32 = octet;
        result != octet32 << (n*8);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The point is that by shifting out byte like this, you avoid any problems with endianness.  The masking also means that if either end has 32-bit chars (such platforms exist), it all works anyway.